# pyside key event invalid

Tags: python, pyside

I'm trying to write an image display function that instantiates the following class and renders the image when I double-click the image, I wanted to close the window by pressing ESC, but it didn't seem to work. The keyPressEvent function was written before copying. It worked before, but it didn't work here. I'm sad.

```
class ImageLabel(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self, imagePath, parent=None):
    super(ImageLabel, self).__init__(parent)
    self.imagePath = imagePath
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    from PIL import Image
    pic_size = (Image.open(self.imagePath).width, Image.open(self.imagePath).height)

    self.image_Label = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.image_Label.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(fileconfig.MAIN_ICON))
    self.image_Label.resize(pic_size[0] + 50, pic_size[1] + 50)
    self.image_Label.setWindowTitle(os.path.basename(self.imagePath))
    self.image_Label.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
    self.image_Label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.imagePath))
    self.image_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.image_Label.show()

def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    key = event.key()
    if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
        self.close()
```

Comment: I have run your code and works perfectly (fixing the identation errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code:

```
from PySide import QtGui,QtCore
import sys
import os
class ImageLabel(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, imagePath, parent=None):
        super(ImageLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.imagePath = imagePath
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        from PIL import Image
        pic_size = (Image.open(self.imagePath).width, 
        Image.open(self.imagePath).height)

        self.image_Label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.image_Label.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(fileconfig.MAIN_ICON))
        self.image_Label.resize(pic_size[0] + 50, pic_size[1] + 50)
        self.image_Label.setWindowTitle(os.path.basename(self.imagePath))
        self.image_Label.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.image_Label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.imagePath))
        self.image_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        # self.image_Label.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    il = ImageLabel('usr/image/img.png')
    il.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I just commented one line `self.image_Label.show()` and everything works fine for me